X and y variable definition for RF split of multiclass classification rating
I have the following variables: text (text of the review), rating (rating of the review 1 to 5), resp_text (managerial response to a review), month_before (binary variable that indicates whether or not the review was 1 month before a managerial response), and month_after (binary variable that indicates whether or not the review was 1 month after a managerial response). The data is sorted both on time and businesses.
I need to respond to the following text - To what extent can using a Random Forest model predict the sentiment of subsequent customer reviews based on managerial responses?
Can anyone help me figure out how to define my X and y variables for the train_test_split ? I have been struggling the whole day and I cant define them.

Without directly giving you the answer, think about what it is you are trying to predict (y) and which information/features/input you want to use to make that prediction (X).

The review text itself is the X variable.
The Y variable is a bit tricky here. Generally, to train for sentiment analysis, we are provided with labelled feature along with the text telling us the sentiment of the text. There could be two things you could do -

Maybe the rating feature could serve as labels. You can create a column where rating < 3 means a negative sentiment and >= 3 means a positive sentiment. Then take the new column as your Y variable.
Your question says, "....based on managerial responses".So, I am confused that maybe the question wants you to take that column as Y. Tell me what kind of data is present in the column resp_text? Is there some way you can derive the sentiment labels from this column or divide this data into positive/negative sentiment labels?


The resp_text contains the text of the managerial response. Its a good idea to create a negative/positive sentiment through the rating column , i didnt think about that. What I guess Im struggling with is that I want to use the managerial responses (resp_text) as the temporal factor that divides the reviews (as in before vs after the managerial response).

You can proceed with the sentiment analysis without considering the managerial response. Once the sentiment analysis is done, you can group by the sentiments based on managerial response and you'll be able to see the difference.

Ill run this through my supervisor tomorrow and see what he thinks about it. Thanks for the feedback!
